# Ansible loop over glob

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create a super complicated, but cool data structure for variables.

*defaults/main.yml*:

```yaml
docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_keycloak_url: http://keycloak:8080
docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_user: admin
docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_user_password: ~
docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_client_id: admin-cli                                                                                                                                                                       
docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_clientsecret: ~
```

Template using those variables

```
#templates/env-vars-keycloak-config-cli
#jinja2: lstrip_blocks: "True"
{% if docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_keycloak_url %}
KEYCLOAK_URL={{ docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_keycloak_url }}
{% endif %}
{% if docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_user %}                                                         
KEYCLOAK_USER={{ docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_user }}
{% endif %}
{% if docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_user_password %}
KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD={{ docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_user_password }}
{% endif %}
{% if docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_client_id %}
KEYCLOAK_CLIENTID={{ docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_client_id }}
{% endif %}
{% if docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_clientsecret %}
KEYCLOAK_CLIENTSECRET={{ docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_clientsecret }}
{% endif %}
{% if docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_granttype %}
KEYCLOAK_GRANTTYPE={{ docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_granttype}}
{% endif %}
{% if docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_loginrealm %}
KEYCLOAK_LOGINREALM={{ docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_loginrealm }}
{% endif %}
{% if docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_sslverify %}
KEYCLOAK_SSLVERIFY={{ docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_sslverify }}
{% endif %}
{% if docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_httpproxy %}
KEYCLOAK_HTTPPROXY={{ docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_httpproxy }}
{% endif %}
{% if docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_connecttimeout %}
KEYCLOAK_CONNECTTIMEOUT={{ docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_connecttimeout }}
{% endif %}
{% if docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_readtimeout %}
KEYCLOAK_READTIMEOUT={{ docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_readtimeout }}
{% endif %}
{% if docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_availabilitycheck_enabled %}
KEYCLOAK_AVAILABILITYCHECK_ENABLED={{ docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_availabilitycheck_enabled }}
{% endif %}
{% if docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_availabilitycheck_timeout %}                                                                                                                                                         
KEYCLOAK_AVAILABILITYCHECK_TIMEOUT={{ docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_availabilitycheck_timeout }}                                                                                                                         
{% endif %}
```

Now, for environment variables you don't really want to add null variables (`~`).

It would be cool to do something like this:

```
#templates/env-vars-keycloak-config-cli
#jinja2: lstrip_blocks: "True"
{% for key, value in docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_envvar_* %}
{% if value -%}
{{key}}={{value}}
{% endif -%}
{% endfor %}
```

This would make my template super short and I don't have to waste time typing so many variables.

Plus, I don't have to rely on a single variable that holds the environment variables. I could edit `host_vars` or `group_vars` with only the one specific variable and not rewrite the big variable.

I.e. make my *defaults/main.yml* looks like this:

```yaml
docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_envvar_keycloak_url: 
  KEYCLOAK_URL: http://keycloak:8080
```

I am testing out how I could loop these variables.

E.g.

```yaml
- name: Create list of vars
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_envvar_* }}"
  tags: test
```

This gave me the error:

```
fatal: [login.cyber.ee]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected 'end of print statement'. String: {{ docker_compose_keycloak_config_envvar_* }}"}
```

How could I gather these type of variables with the glob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: ***"Make the template super short. Edit host_vars or group_vars with only the specific variable."***

A: For example, given the tree

```
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── host_vars
│   ├── host1
│   │   └── keycloak_config_cli.yml
│   ├── host2
│   │   └── keycloak_config_cli.yml
│   └── host3
│       └── keycloak_config_cli.yml
├── pb.yml
└── roles
    └── keycloak
        ├── defaults
        │   └── main.yml
        ├── tasks
        │   └── main.yml
        └── templates
            └── env-vars-keycloak-config-cli.j2
```

and the inventory

```
shell> cat hosts
host1
host2
host3
```

Put the defaults to *defaults/main.yml* and declare the variable *keycloak_config_cli_host*. This variable will serve the purpose of overriding the host-specific attributes if defined

```yaml
shell> cat roles/keycloak/defaults/main.yml 
keycloak_config_cli:
  url: http://keycloak:8080
  user: admin
  password: ~
  client_id: admin-cli
  clientsecret: ~
  timeout: 90
keycloak_config_cli_host: "keycloak_config_cli_{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

For testing, create *host_vars* to override the defaults

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host1/keycloak_config_cli.yml 
keycloak_config_cli_host1:
  timeout: 10
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host2/keycloak_config_cli.yml 
keycloak_config_cli_host2:
  timeout: 20
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host3/keycloak_config_cli.yml 
keycloak_config_cli_host3:
  timeout: 30
```

Create the tasks. Combine the dictionaries in the first task, optionally display the variable, and display the result of the template

```yaml
shell> cat roles/keycloak/tasks/main.yml 
- set_fact:
    keycloak_config_cli: "{{ keycloak_config_cli|
                             combine(lookup('vars',
                                            keycloak_config_cli_host,
                                            default={})) }}"
- debug:
    var: keycloak_config_cli
  when: debug|d(false)|bool
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('template', 'env-vars-keycloak-config-cli.j2') }}"
```

Create the template. It's not very far from your template. Just iterate *items*, reject empty values, and fit the keys

```yaml
shell> cat roles/keycloak/templates/env-vars-keycloak-config-cli.j2 
#templates/env-vars-keycloak-config-cli
#jinja2: lstrip_blocks: "True"
{% for key, value in keycloak_config_cli.items() %}
{% if value -%}
KEYCLOAK_{{ key|regex_replace('_','')|upper }}={{ value }}
{% endif -%}
{% endfor %}
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - keycloak
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************

TASK [keycloak : set_fact] ******************************************************************
ok: [host1]
ok: [host2]
ok: [host3]

TASK [keycloak : debug] *********************************************************************
skipping: [host1]
skipping: [host2]
skipping: [host3]

TASK [keycloak : debug] *********************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: |-
    #templates/env-vars-keycloak-config-cli
    #jinja2: lstrip_blocks: "True"
    KEYCLOAK_URL=http://keycloak:8080
    KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
    KEYCLOAK_CLIENTID=admin-cli
    KEYCLOAK_TIMEOUT=10
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: |-
    #templates/env-vars-keycloak-config-cli
    #jinja2: lstrip_blocks: "True"
    KEYCLOAK_URL=http://keycloak:8080
    KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
    KEYCLOAK_CLIENTID=admin-cli
    KEYCLOAK_TIMEOUT=20
ok: [host3] => 
  msg: |-
    #templates/env-vars-keycloak-config-cli
    #jinja2: lstrip_blocks: "True"
    KEYCLOAK_URL=http://keycloak:8080
    KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
    KEYCLOAK_CLIENTID=admin-cli
    KEYCLOAK_TIMEOUT=30

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************
host1: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host3: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Optionally, override the *defaults* from *group_vars*. Combine the dictionaries from *group_vars* in the sort order

```yaml
shell> cat roles/keycloak/tasks/main.yml
- set_fact:
    keycloak_config_cli: "{{ keycloak_config_cli|
                             combine(lookup('vars',
                                            keycloak_config_cli_group,
                                            default={})) }}"
  loop: "{{ group_names|sort }}"
  vars:
    keycloak_config_cli_group: "keycloak_config_cli_{{ item }}"
  when: enable_group_vars|d(true)|bool

- set_fact:
    keycloak_config_cli: "{{ keycloak_config_cli|
                             combine(lookup('vars',
                                            keycloak_config_cli_host,
                                            default={})) }}"
- debug:
    var: keycloak_config_cli
  when: debug|d(false)|bool
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('template', 'env-vars-keycloak-config-cli.j2') }}"
```

Then, given the additional group in the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
host1
host2
host3

[devel]
host4
```

and the *group_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/devel/keycloak_config_cli.yml
keycloak_config_cli_devel:
  timeout: 40
```

the playbook gives (abridged)

```yaml
...
ok: [host4] => 
  msg: |-
    #templates/env-vars-keycloak-config-cli
    #jinja2: lstrip_blocks: "True"
    KEYCLOAK_URL=http://keycloak:8080
    KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
    KEYCLOAK_CLIENTID=admin-cli
    KEYCLOAK_TIMEOUT=40
```

Answer (score 3):

Ease your own life and simplify / [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) your variables.

Make your *defaults/main.yml* looks like this, where you don't have to keep on repeating *`docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli`* for every single dictionary key:

```yaml
docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli:
  keycloak_url: http://keycloak:8080
  user: admin
  password: ~
  client_id: admin-cli
  clientsecret: ~
  envvar:
    keycloak_url: http://keycloak:8080
```

Then your requirement becomes trivial:

```
{% for key, value in docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli.envvar.items() %}
{{ key | upper }}={{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Which would give you:

```
KEYCLOAK_URL=http://keycloak:8080
```

---

And even better to reduce duplication, use YAML [anchors](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2-old/spec.html#id2785586):

```yaml
docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli:
  keycloak_url: &keycloak_url http://keycloak:8080
  user: admin
  password: ~
  client_id: admin-cli
  clientsecret: ~
  envvar:
    keycloak_url: *keycloak_url
```

---

In order to allow overriding it, recursively [combine](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) the overriding dictionary into the existing variable. Then use it as described above.

```yaml
- set_fact:
    docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli: >-
      {{
        docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli
        | combine(
          docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_override | default({}),
          recursive=True
        )
      }}
```

---

The two tasks:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli: >-
      {{
        docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli
        | combine(
          docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_override | default({}),
          recursive=True
        )
      }}
  vars:
    docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli:
      keycloak_url: &keycloak_url http://keycloak:8080
      user: admin
      password: ~
      client_id: admin-cli
      clientsecret: ~
      envvar:
        keycloak_url: *keycloak_url
        other_env: foo
    docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_override:
      envvar:
        keycloak_url: http://keycloak:80

- debug:
    var: docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli
```

Would yield:

```yaml
docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli:
  client_id: admin-cli
  clientsecret: null
  envvar:
    keycloak_url: http://keycloak:80
    other_env: foo
  keycloak_url: http://keycloak:8080
  password: null
  user: admin
```

Comment: When I go to write group_vars or host_vars and write

docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli:
  password: SECRET

Does it overwrite the whole variable?

Comment: Use another variable then, and in your task, merge de dictionaries recursively.

Comment: ^-- this behaviour is now explained in the edited answer @TaaviAnsper

Answer (score 0):

I am very close to a solution, but I can't figure out how to parse the last parts correctly.

```
  - name: Create list of envvars
    set_fact:
      list_of_envvars: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.varnames', 'docker_compose_keycloak_config_cli_envvar_.+$').split(',') }}"
```

```
#jinja2 template file
{% for envvar in list_of_envvars %}
{{ vars[envvar] }}
{% endfor %}
```

If I try to loop over the vars[envvar] it will only give gime the key of the dict and if I just print it out, it will give me the whole dict.

trying to use lookup('dict', envvar) gives an error. So the only way was to lookup('vars', envvar) which gave me the right thing, but I cant seem to parse it correctly.

---

The output to the file

```
+{'KEYCLOAK_URL': 'http://keycloak:8080'}
 KEYCLOAK_URL
 {'KEYCLOAK_URL': 'http://keycloak:8080'}
+{'KEYCLOAK_USER': 'admin'}
 KEYCLOAK_USER
 {'KEYCLOAK_USER': 'admin'}
```

EDIT:

I solved it:
I had to call the items() function.

```
{% for envvar in list_of_envvars %}
{% set envvars_dict = lookup('vars', envvar) %}
{% for key, value in envvars_dict.items() %}
{% if value %}
{{key}}={{value}}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Use `vars` at your own risks: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/74904#issuecomment-854137949